# While adding any new dependencies in android build.gradle file. it always show an error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> **Error:(42, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0**

When add any dependencies in android build.gradle file it always shows the above error. But same project is running on a different machine same dependencies can add successful. I search lot for solving this problem but can't find any solution. Kindly Please help me to fix the problem Thank you.

I face the same error while adding any dependencies now, but few weeks before i can add any dependencies on my project

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myappid"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
}
repositories {
   jcenter({url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"})
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.0.0'
   // VectorDrawableCompat
   compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.satsuware.lib:usefulviews:2.3.6'
   compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
   compile 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.0.1'
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
  }
```

Comment: do you have java sdk 8 installed. Creating app for Android N requires this ?

Comment: Yes i have java sdk 8 is installed on my machine

Comment: Add your **dependencies like this** 
`compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'`

Comment: wrong statement for adding volley as dependency

Comment: @Rishikesh pathak Also try same thing before but same result.

Comment: @Vivek Mishra I face same problem while adding any dependencies now, but few weeks before i can add any dependencies on my project

Comment: `jcenter({url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"})` looks weird, just use `jcenter()`

Comment: @Egor i already tried it out. still not working

Comment: Run your build from command line using the `-i` flag and investigate the output, there's usually enough information to understand where the problem is.

Comment: @Egor Sir could you help me to run build from command line. this is my first project

Comment: How can I help?

Comment: @Egor tell me how to run build using cmd

Comment: `./gradlew clean assembleDebug -i`

Comment: @Egor where to put this command

Comment: Are you serious? Please use google, dive into Gradle documentation, try to investigate your problem. Sorry, but I don't have enough time to answer this kind of questions.

Comment: @Egor sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122749/discussion-between-jithin-kuriakose-and-egor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try many way to solve the problem i have faced but no one can rectify the problem. I ask the help of may experience developer, they told me that they never face such a problem in there life. So only solution i found is to reinstall android studio. Now it work perfectly. Any way thanks for your support.